# In jQuery is there any method similar to on('click' for checkbox enabled event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have accending and descending sort icons for sorting purposes. On the initial loading, sorting is in an enabled condition
I am in need of a solution similar to below:

```
$('.pgggo-container-ajax-sorting').on('click', '.pgggocheckboxdecendinp', function(event) {
```

say when the descend icon is clicked this function should run. But the above method is not working for a checkbox. Please help

Comment: `change` event? (that'll also fire when changed from enabled to disabled, so check the checkbox's state too)

Comment: Click should work for that too, although `change` is semantically preferred, but we can't diagnose any issues without seeing a working example of the problem.

Comment: `click` and `change` both will work if its normal checkbox, if you using thirdparty then use its own methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$('.pgggo-container-ajax-sorting').on('click', '.pgggocheckboxdecendinp', function(event) {
  if($(this).is(':checked')) {
    //  code for checked condition
  }
  else {
    //  code for unchecked condition
  }
});
```

This will work with checkbox.

Comment: Does it also work in it's checked without using the mouse but only the keyboard?

Comment: Yes, this will.